# "x is 2 greater than y" instead of "x is greater than y by 2"

Tags: prepositions, mathematics

Is saying `x is 2 greater than y` (meaning `x is greater than y by 2`) acceptable?

Comment: I never saw it and I wouldn't know how to interpret it.

Comment: Yes, they are just different ways of expressing the same thing. (In fact, I would prefer the first version to the second—but there's no semantic difference.)

Comment: @probably prefer the second when it comes to phonetics. The 2 in the first example is a homophone of too.

Comment: "x is 2 **more** than y" -- I've not come across *is n greater than ... * in formal writing.

Comment: Sorry, that seems to be but in fact isn't at all to do with Engish.

Could you take that Question to a maths page?